# Saving and updating user karma in the database - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise-invitable

I’m using [acts_as_votable](https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable) and [devise_invitable](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable) in my rails app.

Users can comment and their comments are votable.

Each user has a karma/score

Currently I am showing users karma on their profiles. I don’t actually have their scores saved in the database. I am just calculating it by using this:

```
<% comment_vote_count = current_user.comments.map{|c| c.votes.count}.sum
   comment_vote_count ||=0 
   comment_vote_count *= 2
   total_vote_count = comment_vote_count + current_user.base_score %>
```

base_score acts as an anchor that can manually be changed.

I’m looking to add something to the scoring mechanism. I would like to add 10 points to any given user for each user they invite that actually accepts the invite and signs up.

So the new logic for calculating the users karma should be, the number of votes received on comments times two, plus 10 points for every successful invitation, plus the base score.

More importantly how do I save this in the database? I would like to add a column to the users table called score. But how do I get it to update? Do I get the controller to update it every time the user loads their profile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple plan. First, add a `score` column to your `users` table.

In your `User` model:

```
after_invitation_accepted :increment_score_of_inviter

def increment_score_of_inviter
  invitation_by.increment!(:score, 10)
end

def comment_vote_count
  Vote.find(comment_ids).count * 2
end

def calculated_vote_count
  base_score + comment_vote_count
end

def recalculate_score!
  update_attribute(:score, calculated_vote_count)
end
```

See [devise's invitation callbacks about `after_invitation_accepted`](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable#callbacks)

This could be quite inefficient if you have a lot of voting activity, but to keep the `score` column updated, add this to your `Vote` model:

```
after_create :increment_user_score

def increment_user_score
  user.increment!(:score, 2)
end
```

An alternative here would be to periodically recalculate the `score` column, perhaps using [`whenever`](https://github.com/javan/whenever#example-schedulerb-file) gem:

```
every :hour do
  User.find_each { |u| u.recalculate_score! }
end
```

Comment: This all looks great, but I'm trying to have one value such as score in the database, that I can later sort the users by

Comment: I basically want to be able to sort the users by total_vote_count

Comment: @KatieH would `score` be the same as `total_vote_count`? Notice the `increment!` method. That expects a `score` column in the database (integer).

Comment: Yup! score would be the exact same thing as what your doing in the total_vote_count method!

Comment: In that case, you'll have to update the `score` every time somebody votes. That might be quite inefficient depending on the activity of votes. I'll add an example now. An alternative, and more efficient method would be to periodically recalculate the votes and update the `score` column, perhaps using `whenever` and a `rake` task.

Comment: Could I instead use what you currently wrote, but come up with a way to sort the users based on the total score (calculated_vote_count)?

Comment: Thank you sooooo much!! I'm going to go with the first example, but then how would I sorry the users by calculated_vote_count?

Comment: I've updated the answer to include my suggestions. If you don't have many users and can afford to load them into an array, then you can do this on the fly: `User.all.sort_by(&:calculated_vote_count)`

Comment: Thanks a lot! all looks perfect! Just one last questions, in the methods within the user model, like the increment_score_of_inviter method, how does the method know to update the score of that particular user, should score be user.score? In the comment_vote_count method, how does the method know to search for the votes of a particular user? I guess as a newbie, your code looks really clean refactored :))

Comment: No problem. You don't need to use `user.score` because the methods are within the `User` model (instance methods). That means you can completely skip `user` from within them. Not to add to the confusion, but to refer to `user` within instance methods, you would use `self`, as in `self.comments`, `self.id`, etc.